# Is it possible to calculate standard deviation from d (effect size)? How do you do it?

Tags: standard-deviation, meta-analysis

I am doing a meta-analysis and one of the papers report d instead of SD. I do also have sample size and mean for each group, but I don't have the SD for each group.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of simple algebra should suffice here.

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the means which you say you have, $d$ be Cohen's $c$ and $s$ be the pooled standard deviation.

$$
d = \frac{X_1 - X_2}{s}
$$

Multiply both sides by $s$

$$
s * d = X_1 - X_2
$$

Now divide both sides by $d$

$$
s = \frac{X_1 - X_2}{d}
$$

which is the desired result.

Note that this is more complex if what they are reporting is not in fact Cohen's $d$ but the bias corrected version usually known as Hedges' $g$.